# OAuth2 issue with Google in .NET 8 and Swagger - Endpoints calling with a 302 Found status

Tags: .net, swagger, google-oauth

I'm facing an issue with OAuth2 authentication using Google in a .NET 8 application with Swagger. After using Authenticate in swagger it takes me to google login page, after login i am redirected back to swagger but when I try to make any endpoint call, from developers console it seems that the endpoint is being called with a additional call to google auth with 302 Found status. The request details are as follows:

```
Request URL: https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/v2/auth?client_id=[MY-ID]&scope=openid profile
```

email&response_type=code&redirect_uri=https://localhost:5001/signin-google&code_challenge=[MOCK]&code_challenge_method=S256&state=[MOCK]
Request Method: GET
Status Code: 302 Found
Referrer Policy: strict-origin-when-cross-origin

Here's my authentication and Swagger configuration:

```
private static void AddIdentityProvider(IServiceCollection services, IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        services.AddAuthentication(options =>
            {
                options.DefaultScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
                options.DefaultChallengeScheme = GoogleDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
            })
            .AddCookie(option =>
            {
                option.Cookie.Name = "DomainName";
            })
            .AddGoogle(options =>
            {
                options.ClientId = configuration["Google:ClientId"] ?? throw new InvalidConfigurationException("Google:ClientId is missing");
                options.ClientSecret = configuration["Google:ClientSecret"] ?? throw new InvalidConfigurationException("Google:ClientSecret is missing");
                options.CallbackPath = "/signin-google";
                
                options.Scope.Add("email");
                options.Scope.Add("openid");
            });

        services.AddAuthorizationBuilder();
    }

private static void AddSwagger(IServiceCollection services, IConfiguration configuration)
{
    services.AddSwaggerGen(options =>
    {
        options.SwaggerDoc("v1", new OpenApiInfo { Title = "Domain Api", Version = "v1" });

        options.AddSecurityDefinition("Bearer", new OpenApiSecurityScheme
        {
            Name = "Authorization",
            Type = SecuritySchemeType.OAuth2,
            Flows = new OpenApiOAuthFlows
            {
                AuthorizationCode = new OpenApiOAuthFlow
                {
                    AuthorizationUrl = new Uri(GoogleDefaults.AuthorizationEndpoint),
                    TokenUrl = new Uri(GoogleDefaults.TokenEndpoint),
                    Scopes = new Dictionary<string, string>
                    {
                        { "openid", "openid" },
                        { "email", "email" },
                    }
                }
            }
        });
        ;

        options.AddSecurityRequirement(new OpenApiSecurityRequirement
        {
            {
                new OpenApiSecurityScheme
                {
                    Reference = new OpenApiReference
                    {
                        Type = ReferenceType.SecurityScheme,
                        Id = "Bearer"
                    }
                },
                new List<string>()
            }
        });

        options.OperationFilter<EnableQueryOperationFilter>();
    });
}
```

Swagger UI configured like:

```
app.UseSwaggerUI(c =>
{
    c.OAuthClientId(builder.Configuration["Google:ClientId"]);
    c.OAuthClientSecret(builder.Configuration["Google:ClientSecret"]);
    c.OAuthUsePkce();

    c.OAuthAppName("Domain");
    c.DisplayRequestDuration();
    c.DefaultModelExpandDepth(0);
    c.DefaultModelsExpandDepth(-1);
});
```

Basically if i copy and pase Request URL in browser it redirects me to google login, after sucessfull login it redirects me back to desired endpoint, cookie is set and all endpoints work.

I'm seeking guidance on identifying and resolving this issue. Any insights or suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!